# Android relative layout center every elements

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have written a fragment in a tabbed layout that looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to have all the contents (buttons, editTextes and textViewes) in the center of the screen. I am pretty new with Android, so my question is: can I create a "box" (like the one I have painted in blue) containing all the stuff and center it vertically?

[image]

In the picture above you can see what I need. Here you can find the XML code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/rad_grad"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#26D50D" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint1"
    android:ems="10" >

</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="@string/convert" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:editable="false" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<View
    android:id="@+id/sepbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/grad_rad"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#26D50D"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sepbar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/hint2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="@string/convert" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:editable="false"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/devname"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your relative layout in a vertical Linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- top view -->
    <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <!-- bottom view -->
    <Relative2>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**  After taking a closer look at your layout, it should work.  Remove the LayoutBelow on the sepbar and base the components above and below off of it.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/sepbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
 --> Remove me   android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

I don't use the relative layout much anymore, there are specific cases when I do, but I generally find myself using more linear layouts for stuff like this.  Relative can be a headache to get right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LinearLayout with vertical orientation.... the main thing is "the concept" the layout which you provided above is better to use with linearlayout instead of relativelayout because in relativelayouts we have lot ripple effects due to id change... and the above layout is of monotonous type "vertical" ... from my experience i prefer to use relativelayout when i have unordered layout like a bear in the center then a bird on its left top and a ball on bears right center aligned etc...

As for the layout in blue here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:android:gravity="center"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" <!--(hear you can imagine like this if you give wrap content then linearlayout gravity will be used but if you use match_parent then u will have to use gravity here else android default ltr gravity will be used )-->
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Radianti..."/>
      <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"<!--(im using match_parent because its going to be this edittext child which needs gravity so the parent linearlayout gravity wont work on this edittext contents {child})-->
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:android:gravity="center"
           android:text="my edit text content..."/>

           <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:android:gravity="center"
             android:orientation="horizontal"<!--note this it will place itself vertically in parent now we can place its child contents horizontally-->
             >
              <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="button"/>
              <EditText
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="another etx"/>
             <!-- you can use layout_weight in linearlayout to give width in percentage value ranges from 0 1 i guess decimal is allowed i used like 0.4 and 0.6 so it means 40 percent and 60 percent you can read about it more... -->
         </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Hope  this will help you to BUILD THE CONCEPT :)

Thanks